# Unable to access the yugabyte tserver and master admin ui

Tags: yugabytedb

I'm new in YugaByte. It's really great for scaling purpose.
I've created a 3 node cluster in AWS EC2. It's running fine and status is also proper. But when I'm trying to access the Admin UI for the YB-TServer and Master from my local machine using the EC2 instance public IP, it's unable to reach. How to configure the admin ui access binding?

TServer URL: http://EC2-IP:9000
Master URL: http://EC2-IP:7000

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you have allowed the 7000/9000 ports for external access via AWS Admin Console? Documentation is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: I've allowed the 700 and 900 port from AWS admin console. Still not able to connect.

Comment: Can you try changing https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/reference/configuration/yb-tserver/#webserver-interface to the same ip as https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/reference/configuration/yb-tserver/#rpc-bind-addresses ?